# Determine if a Url is absolute or relative from vb

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to determine in vb if a URL is absolute or relative.  I'm sure there has to be some library that can do this but I'm not sure which.  Basically I need to be able to analyze a string such as 'relative/path' and or 'http://www.absolutepath.com/subpage' and determine whether it is absolute or relative.  Thanks in advance.

-Ben

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the [`Uri.IsWellFormedUriString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring.aspx) method, which takes a [`UriKind`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.urikind.aspx) as an argument, specifying whether you're checking for absolute or relative.

```
bool IsAbsoluteUrl(string url) {
    if (!Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)) {
        throw new ArgumentException("URL was in an invalid format", "url");
    }
    return Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(url, UriKind.Absolute);
}

IsAbsoluteUrl("http://www.absolutepath.com/subpage"); // true
IsAbsoluteUrl("/subpage"); // false
IsAbsoluteUrl("subpage"); // false
IsAbsoluteUrl("http://www.absolutepath.com"); // true
```

Comment: If you're checking to see if the URL will send the user to a different domain this fails.  It doesn't handle protocol-relative URLs.  `//gmail.com` is considered relative, not absolute, to System.Uri.  Browsers will assume the current scheme/protocol, but System.Uri doesn't handle that case.

Answer (score 4):

[Determine if Absolute or Relative URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002692/c-sharp-determine-if-absolute-or-relative-url) has simpler [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4002717/52277)

```
bool IsAbsoluteUrl(string url) 
        { 
            Uri result; 
            return Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.Absolute, out result);                 
        }
```

Comment: Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(url, UriKind.Absolute) is pretty simple, too. Also it's probably faster, since it's not trying to create a new Uri.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.absolutepath.com/subpage");
Console.WriteLine(uri.IsAbsoluteUri);
```

**Edit**: If you're not sure that address is well-formed, you should to use:

```
static bool IsAbsolute(string address, UriKind kind)
{
    Uri uri = null;
    return Uri.TryCreate(address, kind, out uri) ? 
        uri.IsAbsoluteUri : false;
}
```

Comment: If you're checking to see if the URL will send the user to a different domain this fails.  It doesn't handle protocol-relative URLs.  `//gmail.com` is considered relative, not absolute, to System.Uri.